# Importing .json model into Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am new to Three.js and I don't quite understand the model loading.

I have this function which creates a block and another function textures it.

```
function initThreeAgent()
{
 var shape    = new THREE.BoxGeometry( squaresize, squaresize, squaresize );             
 theagent = new THREE.Mesh( shape );
 theagent.material.color.setHex( BLANKCOLOR );  
 drawAgent();         
}
```

But let's say I don't want this to be a box, I want it to be a .json model. I know I have to use something like this but I can't quite put it all together.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( '/uploads/SeanHutchinson/Sporty_Man.json', function ( geometry ) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
```

How can I change the initThreeAgent function to use the above model instead?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you've come as far as the code above, you've probably tried this already, but there are some small corrections included here:

```
function initThreeAgent() {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    function loaded(geometry) {
        theagent = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
        theagent.material.color.setHex(BLANKCOLOR);
        drawAgent();
    }

    loader.load('/uploads/SeanHutchinson/Sporty_Man.json', loaded);         
}
```

There are some caveats here, which I'm assuming you're doing elsewhere:

1. `theAgent` needs to be added to the scene
2. The callback you had was malformed, so I broke it out as the `loaded` function. You can move it back into the load call if you wish.
3. The call to `drawAgent` needs to be in the callback, because the load method is asynchronous, and loading a large model may take some time.